# Ayuden con Problemas en Z-INDEX,

Tags: html, css, web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO HTML :::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilosprincipal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter+One|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter+One|K2D" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hi+Melody" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <!-- BARRA LOGO Y MENU -->

    <div class="row nav rounded-top align-items-stretch justidy-content-between">
      <!-- LOGOTIPO -->

      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg logo d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="img/logo.png" width="130" height="100" alt="">
           <span class="icono icon-dot "></span> 
           <p>AmisCake</p></a>     
      </div>
      <!------ NAVEGACIOM REDES SOCIALES ------->
      <div class="row rounded-top align-items-stretch justidy-content-between">
        <nav  class="navbar nav2 navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-fondonav ">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
              <li class="nav-item " >
                <a class="nav-link"  href="#" style="color: #000"> <i class="fas fa-home iconosmenu"></i> Inicio  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"  href="#" style="color: #000"><i class="fas fa-question iconosmenu"></i> Nosotros </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"   href="#" style="color: #000"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume iconosmenu"></i> Contacto </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Categorias <i class="fas fa-utensils iconosmenu"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#item-1">Postres</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pudines</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ----------MENU DE NAVEGACION ------------ -->

    <!-- JUMBOTRON LLAMATIVO LADING PAGE -->

    <div class="row rounded-top align-items-stretch justidy-content-between">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4 textjumbutron">Postres y Pudines</h1>
          <p class="lead">Los mejores postres y pudines los encuentras donde AmisCake, de calidad y caceros.</p>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <h6 class="textoregistro">Registrare y obten un 30% de descuento hoy!</h6>
          <a class="btn btn-registro btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Registrar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CODIGO CSS:::

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;
}


header{
    margin-top: 30px;
}


header .nav{
    border-top: 6px solid rgb(31,169,167);
    min-height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 0;

}
.nav2{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;

}

header .nav2 a:hover{ 
    text-decoration: underline rgb(31,169,167);
}

/*------COLOR DE LA OPCION CATEGORIAS DEL MENU*/
#navbarDropdownMenuLink{
    color: #000;
}

/*-----BOTON PARA BAJAR HACIA BAJO */

.btn-scroll{
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 38px 5px 0px 0px;
background-color: rgb(235,112,119); ;
color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;

}

/*-----LOGOTIPO-----*/
header .logo img,
header .logo span,
header .logo p{ 
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

/*----- CONFIGURANDO TAMAÑO DEL LOGO PARA PONERLO MAS ALADO DEL TEXTO -----*/
header .logo img{
margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}


header .logo p{
    color: #777777;
}

/*------ MENU DE NAVEGACION ------*/
.nav2{
    background-color: #fff;

}

.iconosmenu{
    color: rgb(31,169,167);

}

/*----- JMBOTRON -------*/
.jumbotron{
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    height: 420px;
}

/*-----TEXTO DENTRO DEL JUMBUTRON*/
.textjumbutron {
    font-size: 40px;
}
.lead{
    font-size: 18px;
}

/*----- TEXTO DENTRO DEL JUMBOTRON-----*/
.textoregistro{
    font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
    font-family: 'K2D', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;

}
/*----- BOTON DENTRO DEL JUMBOTRON-----*/
.btn-registro{
    background-color: rgb(31,169,167);
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-registro:hover{
    background-color: rgb(116,76,39);
    color: #fff;
}


/*-----MENU DE REDES SOCIALES-----*/

header .menu {
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
}

header .menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

header .menu a div span {
    font-weight: 600;

}

header .menu .c-1 {background: rgb(55,80,162); color: #fff;}
header .menu .c-2 {background: rgb(201,45,162); color: #fff;}
header .menu .c-3 {background: rgb(28,156,234); color: #fff;}

header .menu .c-1:hover {background: rgb(79,91,213); color: #fff;}
header .menu .c-2:hover {background: rgb(150,47,191); color: #fff;}
header .menu .c-3:hover {background: rgb(64,143,203); color: #fff;}


/*-------IMAGENES DE LA SECCION*/
.portafolio{
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.portafolio .titulo{
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3da5e2;
    font-weight: 300;

}
.portafolio .fotos .contenedor-imagen{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imagen1{
    height: 177px;
    width: 700px;
}

.imagen3{
    height: 252px;
    width: 700px;
}
#textoventa{
    padding: 12px;
    color: rgb(31,169,167);
}

.zoom{
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10PX;
    border-radius: 18px;

}

.zoom:hover
{-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.03);transition: all 0.5s;}


/*FONDO AL CONTENEDOR DE PRODUCTOS*/
.product{
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px grey;


}

.precio{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Estaría bien que pasarás por el [tour] y leyeras [ask]. No has explicado tu problema, solo has puesto una imagen y un montón de código y es dificil darte una solución sin información sobre lo que quieres conseguir y dónde está el problema

Comment: prueba con nav.navbar{z-index: 100 !important;} o lo mismo pero con div.dropdown-menu [A más z-index le pongas, más arriba estará ese elemento]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente?